# Running Selenium tests with IE using python

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

The installation page [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) says to add the selenium server standalone jar to the CLASSPATH. What does the jar do? Do I need it? I ran some selenium code already and it works without it. I just instantiated IE doing

`driver = driver.Ie()`

I am running webdriver (selenium 2) in Python, trying to test IE9 (and then after test IE8). (I'm not using .NET, just running a .py file) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was the jar you needed to run with "Selenium 1".  It is not necessary with Selenium 2 as far as I know.  It may be used when doing remote testing (I haven't done that with Selenium 2), but it is definitely not needed for local testing.