# Internet Explorer webdriver for selenium grid

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium-grid, selenium-webdriver

Do I need to have the IE webdriver? I'm using python and I can get IE up and running with selenium grid 2 by

```
        c = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
        driver = webdriver.Remote(url, c)
```

so what is the webdriver for (selenium 1 only?)

I found a similar question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001974/running-selenium-tests-with-ie-using-python) but I'll be using Selenium Grid 2, not testing locally.

Answer (score 0):

Any node advertisting that it can run a WebDriver IE session must have the IEDriver installed, yes.  As of the most recent releases, this means IE driver server executable must be on the PATH.

Comment: How come it works without the driver? Also, I'm confused on what this is trying to say:

Comment: [from here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) it talks about running IEDriverServer.exe remotely:
The HTTP server started by the IEDriverServer.exe disallows incoming connections from remote machines. To run the Internet Explorer driver on a remote machine, use the Java standalone remote server in connection with your language binding's equivalent of RemoteWebDriver. (I have the IE driver running from adding -Dwebdriver.internetexplorer.driver to the role command and everything works)

Comment: So rather than place the IEDriverServer.exe on the PATH, you specified the path to it.  That's fine as well.  I'm not sure what your actual question is though.